# Error: permission denied on key 'fs.file-nr'

Tags: files, limit, sysctl

I am running this command as root:

```
# sysctl -w fs.file-nr=131072
error: permission denied on key 'fs.file-nr'
```

Same issue when I edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and try `sysctl -p`. Any reason why I cannot edit this value?

I am on CentOS 6.5

Comment: What user are you using, root?  Check if that file is immutable with `lsattr filename`

Comment: Yes, I am root. Where would I find fs.file-nr?

Answer (score 3):

`fs.file-nr` represents the number of allocated file handles, the number of allocated but unused ones, and the maximum number of file handles, which is `read-only`.

However the third field can be modified through `fs.file-max` instead.

`# sysctl -w fs.file-max=131072`